# Can I attach external video/webcam to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, video-capture

A friend wants to run a videoconference app (Zoom) on his TV. He can stream Zoom from his iOS devices to the TV, but he needs a wider angle.

I should know this, but is there a way to connect an external webcam?

Thanks

Comment: i doubt this would be possible. but you can use clip-on wide angle lens on the builtin camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes!
you can search " uvc webcam to lightning" converter

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google search finds multiple products and guides for using a webcam with an Android phone, but the same search with "Android" switched to "iPhone" shows nothing. This makes sense, as historically iOS devices have never had native USB support, neither for printing nor keyboards nor flash drives nor anything else. I'd be surprised if they relaxed the security restrictions only for webcams.

Comment: never had native USB support? ok, if "native" means without any adapters. otherwise you can use the apple "camera adapter" and connect some usb devices. according to apple, webcams are not supported. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202034

Comment: @szulat I didn't know about this, thanks. Feel free to edit my answer to be more correct